# Alignment/spacing issue with last activity on Home page

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, homepage, last-activity

The last activity on a question is sometimes misaligned/improperly spaced on the Home page. This is possibly due to a long username *combined* with a lengthy activity description?

Observed on Safari on iOS. I am using the responsive design.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean the m in "modified" is cut off?

Comment: @Unconsidered Yes, and the 7 in “74.4k”.

Comment: As best as I can tell, this bug has been fixed with the recent changes to the Home page questions design (see "[New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/986753)").